# Error with pydub in python

Tags: python, pydub

i have successfully imported pydub
but for the code:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
song = AudioSegment.from_mp3("c:\mks.mp3")
first_ten_seconds = song[:10000]
song.export("d:\mks.mp3", format="mp3")
```

But it gives the following error:

```
python "C:\Users\mKs\Desktop\mks2.py"
Process started >>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mKs\Desktop\mks2.py", line 2, in <module>
    song=AudioSegment.from_mp3("c:\mks.mp3");
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pydub-0.5.2-py2.7.egg\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 194, in from_mp3
    return cls.from_file(file, 'mp3')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pydub-0.5.2-py2.7.egg\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 189, in from_file
    return cls.from_wav(output)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pydub-0.5.2-py2.7.egg\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 206, in from_wav
    return cls(data=file)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pydub-0.5.2-py2.7.egg\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 33, in __init__
    raw = wave.open(StringIO(data), 'rb')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wave.py", line 498, in open
    return Wave_read(f)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wave.py", line 163, in __init__
    self.initfp(f)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wave.py", line 128, in initfp
    self._file = Chunk(file, bigendian = 0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\chunk.py", line 63, in __init__
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

I would love to get help on this topic

Comment: how long is your msk.mp3?

Comment: Please remove ";" at the end of the lines.

Comment: Fyi, semi-colons are fine in Python. Although they're optional and serve no real purpose, so no one bothers to use them.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue that I see with your code is trailing ";" at the end of last 3 line. Please remove those, and see if you still get the error.

In addition, make sure you have [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) (http://www.ffmpeg.org/) installed. It is required for the support of all of the none wav file formats.

**ADDED:**

I think you have broken module dependencies in your python installation. 
I have tried code that you provided above with python 2.7.2. It worked fine for me:

```
>>> from pydub import AudioSegment
>>> song = AudioSegment.from_wav('goodbye.wav')
>>> first_ten_seconds = song[:10000]
>>> song.export('goodbye1.wav',format='wav')
<open file 'goodbye1.wav', mode 'wb+' at 0x10cf2b270>
```

Comment: have you installed ffmpeg (http://www.ffmpeg.org/)? It is required for all none wav file formats.

Comment: This library makes a call to the `ffmpeg` command. see https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/pydub/audio_segment.py#L208 You need to install it and be able to type `ffmpeg` into the command line without getting an error.

Comment: i m able to use ffmpeg with cmp prmpt but still the error is the same

Comment: Have you tried wav file. If not, try it first. It is supposed to be natively supported by pydub.

Comment: with wav if i do this: from pydub import AudioSegment song = AudioSegment.from_wav("c:\Explosion.wav") it works , but if i add the line: song.export("d:\abc.wav","wav") then there comes the error : Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\mKs\Desktop\mks2.py", line 3, in <module> song.export("abc.wav","wav") File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pydub-0.5.2-py2.7.egg\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 239, in export data.unlink(data.name) File "C:\Python27\lib\tempfile.py", line 376, in getattr a = getattr(file, name) AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'unlink

Comment: so what do u think the problem is for the last statement: song.export("abc.wav","wav")

Comment: Have you checked file/folder permissions?